# Android, Can I use putExtra to pass multiple values

Tags: android, parameters

I want to pass two values to another activity can I do this with putExtra or do I have to do it a more complicated way, which it seems from my reading. E.g.. can something like this work?

```
public final static String ID_EXTRA="com.fnesse.beachguide._ID";

Intent i = new Intent(this, CoastList.class);
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, "1", "111");
startActivity(i);
```

The above gives an error.

**Edit**

The first thing I tried was similar to:

```
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA1, "1");
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA2, "111");
```

but ID_EXTRA2 seems to write over ID_EXTRA1

So,

```
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, new String[] { "1", "111"});
```

Looks like the go but how do I extract the values from the array in the second activity, I have been using this for a single value.

```
passedVar = getIntent().getStringExtra(CoastList.ID_EXTRA);
```

I guess I have to turn ID_EXTRA into an array somehow???

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can pass multiple values by using multiple keys. Instead of

```
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, "1", "111");
```

do

```
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA1, "1");
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA2, "111");
```

Of course you have to define 2 constants for the keys and have to read both seperately in the new activity.

Or you can pass a string array via

```
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, new String[] { "1", "111"});
```

Comment: @MikeClarke Make sure that ID_EXTRA1 and ID_EXTRA2 don't have the same values assigned to them *(e.g. both have `com.fnesse.beachguide._ID`)*. Otherwise they count as the same key, which would trigger the overwrite. And if you try to use the array, use `getIntent().getStringArrayExtra()` instead of `getIntent().getStringExtra()`.

Comment: Can you please tell how many strings we can pass at a time from one activity to another?  There should be a limit to what we can intent, so that the app does not get crashed??

Answer (score 165):

You could pass a 'bundle' of extras rather than individual extras if you like, for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("EXTRA_USERNAME","my_username");
extras.putString("EXTRA_PASSWORD","my_password");
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your Activity that your triggering, you can reference these like so:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String username_string = extras.getString("EXTRA_USERNAME");
String password_string = extras.getString("EXTRA_PASSWORD");
```

Or (if you prefer):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String username_string = extras.getString("EXTRA_USERNAME");
String password_string = extras.getString("EXTRA_PASSWORD");
```

Answer (score 11):

Putting extra values in class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        public final static String USERNAME = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
        public final static String EMAIL = "com.example.myfirstapp.EMAIL";

public void registerUser(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText userNameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText emailTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String userName = userNameTxt.getText().toString();
        String email = emailTxt.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(USERNAME, userName);
        intent.putExtra(EMAIL,email);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Reading extra values from another class

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String user = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.USERNAME);
        String email = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EMAIL);
```

Answer (score 3):

Passing bundle of extra **for kotlin coders**

```
val intent = Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java)
val extras = Bundle().apply {
    putString("EXTRA_USERNAME", "my_username")
    putString("EXTRA_PASSWORD", "my_password")
}
intent.putExtras(extras)
startActivity(intent)
```

Then retrieve your values in the other activity like below:

```
val extras = getIntent().extras
val username_string = extras?.getString("EXTRA_USERNAME")
val password_string = extras?.getString("EXTRA_PASSWORD")
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't but you can pass an array using:

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, String[] value)
```

like this for example:

```
i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, new String[]{"1", "111"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example won't work, since the `Extras` are made out of a `Key` and a `Value`. You cant put multiple `Keys` and `Values` in one `Extra`

Also, your keys need to be `Strings` as far as I know (and noticed) but I might be wrong on that one.

Try this:

```
public final static String ID_EXTRA="com.fnesse.beachguide._ID";

Intent i = new Intent(this, CoastList.class);
i.putExtra("ID_Extra", ID_EXTRA);
i.putExtra("1", 111);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single small amount of value **putExtra** is perfect but when you pass multiple values and need to pass custom **ArrayList or List** then I think it's a bad idea. Solution is you can use **[Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)**. You and also use **[Singleton](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/singleton-1577166.html)** or **[Serializable](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45)** also.

**Parcelable:**

> Parcelable class which you need to share.

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

> Form your activity where you want to send

```
MyParcelable example = new MyParcelable();
.....
.....
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("example", Parcels.wrap(example));
```

> From another activity where you want to receive

```
MyParcelable example = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("example"));
```