# Pass two values via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I'm trying to create a shortcut for an another application's activity (which is mine too). The shortcut starts the activity correctly, but just one of the two extras is received (or sent, I don't know). See the code below:

```
//Setting up the intent
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("num", 12);
intent.putExtra("name", "something");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName
    ("com.myanother.app","com.myanother.app.MyActivity"));
```

And the other activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int num = extras.getInt("num"); //this worked
        String name = extras.getString("name"); //this gets null
```

So, what's wrong? And sorry for my English if I made some mistakes.

Comment: check if you are sending any other data with the same key "name" or chnage this key to some other word

Comment: I've tried to change the key name, but it didn't worked too. And there aren't other data with the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bundle bund = new Bundle();

bund.putInt("num",12);
bund.putString("name","hello world");

Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.putExtras(bund);

intent.setComponent(new ComponentName
("com.myanother.app","com.myanother.app.MyActivity"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to put in multiple extras you can try to pass a bundle as an extra. Look [at the first answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452526/android-can-i-use-putextra-to-pass-multiple-values). The question is similar and the solution should be work.