# Activity started from background or for another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

How do I know if an Activity **A** **was started from Intent**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

or due to **activity lifecycle** (after destroy, activity A can be created again, if it is on *history applications*).

*Is there some way to distinguish these two ways to invoke an Activity?*

[image: Android Activity Lifecyce]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **`PutExtras()`** on the `Intent` `Activity`

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452526/android-can-i-use-putextra-to-pass-multiple-values) or this-indirect-[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875772/unknown-intent-flag-on-launcher-activity)

When your `Activity` is Recreated it is created with a different `Intent` not the `Intent` that was used to spark it initially-(especially from history), so if you use extras and check in your oncreate you will be better of -(read this with regards to the not soo much indirect post)

Comment: This approach using `putExtras(.)` is more applicable to this scenario, bcause `Intent` coming from `Activity` can not loose its `mExtras`.

Answer (score 2):

So if I understood you want to check if `onCreate` it's called a second time. You can achieve that by using this logic:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedIntanceState != null && savedIntanceState.getBooleanExtra("FIRST_RUN", false)){
        //not a first run
    }
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("FIRST_RUN", true);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```